# Prove that the number of pairs of edges that cross in a drawing of $K_n$ is at least $\frac{1}{5}\binom{n}{4}$ (for $n\geq 5$)

Tags: graph-theory

Here, $K_n$ is the complete graph on $n$ vertices.

The only thing I can think of is induction on the number of vertices. The claim holds for $n=5$; this is easy to check. I was thinking of assuming that it holds for $n-1$ and then consider a drawing of $K_{n-1}$ with a minimal number of crossings. Then add a vertex at each crossing to form a planar graph $L$, and then somehow get a lower bound $k$ on the size of a face $L$. Then when you add a vertex to $K_{n-1}$ to form $K_n$ it is in one of the faces of $L$, and it adds at least $n-1-k$ crossings.

But I can't get this to work out at all and I suspect it's a completely dead end.

Comment: It may help others if you properly define $K_n$. Or does the use of "drawing" give it a precise meaning?

Comment: @JaycobColeman good point, done.

Comment: It probably is a dead end - the problem is that a 'best-case graph' for $K_{n-1}$ isn't necessarily obtained by restricting the best-case graph for $K_n$, so you can't simply assume that $K_{n-1}$ can be extended in this fashion.

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory) ? It gives a proof for a bound that evaluates to $\theta(n^4)$ for the complete graph, so it's of the right order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick any five vertices. Then, as $K_5$ is not planar, there is a pair of edges in the graph generated by these 5 vertices which cross.

Thus, we get at least one crossing for every combination of $5$ vertices. In total, our count is at least $\binom{n}{5}$.

But, we might had counted the same crossing multiple times. Look at a crossing: lets say $v_iv_j$ and $v_kv_l$.We counted this crossing at most $n-4$ times: we might have counted it in the quintle $v_i v_j v_k v_l v_s$ where $1 \leq s \leq n$ and $s \neq i, s \neq j , s\neq l s\neq m$.

If $k$ is the number of crossings, and we counted each crossing at most $n-4$ times, our count is at most $k(n-4)$. Thus

$$k(n-4) \geq \binom{n}{5}\,.$$

Thus the number of crossings is at least

$$\frac{\binom{n}{5}}{n-4}=\frac{1}{5}\binom{n}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

A *crossing* in a drawing of $K_n$ is an unordered pair $\{e,f\}$ of edges which cross each other but have no endpoint in common, i.e., they have $4$ distinct endpoints between them. If $x=\{e,f\}$ is a crossing, let $V(X)$ be the set consisting of the $4$ endpoints of $e$ and $f$.

Let $f(n)$ be the *crossing number* of $K_n$, i.e., the minimum possible number of crossings in a drawing of $K_n$ in the plane. We know that$f(5)=\frac15\binom54$. In order to prove that $f(n)\ge\frac15\binom n4$ for all $n\ge5$, it will suffice to show that $f(n)/\binom n4$ is a nondecreasing function of $n$.

Consider any $n\ge5$. I want to show that $f(n)/\binom n4\ge f(n-1)/\binom{n-1}4$, i.e., that $(n-4)f(n)\ge nf(n-1)$.

Consider a drawing of $K_n$ with exactly $f(n)$ crossings. Let $S$ be the set of all pairs $(X,v)$ such that $X$ is a crossing in $K_n$ and $v$ is a vertex in $V(K_n)\setminus V(X)$. Choosing $X$ first, we see that $|S|=(n-4)f(n)$. Choosing $v$ first, we see that $|S|\ge nf(n-1)$. Thus $(n-4)f(n)\ge nf(n-1)$, Q.E.D.

Since $f(5)=1$, it follows that $f(n)\ge\frac15\binom n4$ for all $n\ge5$. Likewise, if we know (e.g. from [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000241) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_%28graph_theory%29)) that $f(7)=9$, it follows that $f(n)\ge\frac9{35}\binom n4$ for all $n\ge7$. Moreover, it is easy to see that there is a constant $c\gt0$ such that $f(n)\sim c\binom n4\sim\frac n{24}n^4$ as $n\to\infty$. The same arguments apply, e.g., to the [*rectilinear crossing number*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RectilinearCrossingNumber.html) of $K_n$, i.e., the minimum number of crossings in a drawing of $K_n$ in which edges are drawn as straight line segments.

Comment: Two things: (1) Why must there be as many crossings as 'krossings'?  The 'krossing sets' don't have to be independent, and the crossing in a given krossing can contribute to many krossings.  (2) Where does your final argument use anything about the specific properties of krossings?  I don't see how it doesn't prove the same thing about any arbitrary graph property.

Comment: (Actually, adding my own answer to (2) : it doesn't use anything about _krossings_, but it uses the *decomposability* of $K_n$ essentially; it's not actually related to krossings at all, but That's Okay.  I'm still not sure about (1), though...

Comment: I don't see how "the crossing in a given krossing contribute to many krossings"? If edge $ab$ crosses edge $cd$, that contributes to the krossing $\{a,b,c,d\}$, period. Are you thinking of drawings where $ab$ crosses $ac$, or $ab$ crosses $ab$? OK, by a "krossing" I mean a drawing of $K_4$ in which **two independent edges** (so they have $4$ distinct endpoints) cross.

Comment: Regarding (2), this simple argument is indeed very general. For instance, in Ramsey theory: It's easy to see that any coloring of the edges of $K_6$ with $2$ colors contains at least $2$ monochromatic triangles. It follows from that (by the same argument I used in my answer) that, for $n\ge6$, any coloring of the edges of $K_n$ with $2$ colors contains at least $\frac1{10}\binom n3$ monochromatic triangles.

Comment: Ahh, I've got it.  Somehow I had a mental image of a 'krossing' (boy, does my autocorrect hate that term) as a thing that was a property of just a couple of the elements $a,b,c,d$ - I think as though those were edges rather than vertices.  But obviously any 'krossing' can only belong to one $K_4$, since it involves four distinct vertices.  What you're saying makes perfect sense to me.  Thank you!